# Does the Rydberg Formula work if the electron is going from lower to higher levels?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, wavelength

In all of the internet, all I see is examples about the *Rydberg Formula* about an electron going from *higher levels* to *lower levels* (like from $n=6$ to $n=3$ ), and it does make sense to be honest, because atom will emit light with a specific wavelength.

But if electron goes from $n=1$ to $n=3$ for example, atom will absorb light with specific wavelength, but if we put this in the *Rydberg Formula*, we get a negative wavelength.

So i just want to know, if my logic is correct for going from *lower* to *higher*? And should we put a negative sign instead in the *Rydberg Formula* in this case? Or what should i do?

*Thanks in advance* for answering **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you are right. Negative wavelengths don't make sense. However, since all equations require interpretation, you could interpret negative wavelengths as the wavelengths of light that an atom absorbs rather than emits. For another interpretation, start by multiplying both sides of the Rydberg equation by $hc$.
$$\frac{hc}{\lambda}=hcR\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$
$$E_{photon}=hcR\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$
$$\Delta E_{atom}=hcR\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$
Now we have a calculation of the change in energy of an atom, which can be positive or negative.

Comment: Oh okay thanks man!